# Is it a good practice to return final express response from a nested callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am in situation where I have nested callback functions, and if a certain condition has been met, I need to return a response to the user immediately without jumping up to the parent functions. Example

```
const func = (res) => {
    func2(res,(result)=> {
        // some logic
        func3(res,(result)=> {
          if(true){
             res.json({message: true})
          }
       })
    })
}
```

My question is: Does sending a final express response from a callback function as done in the example above aborts the work done after it from the parent functions(func2, and func1)? or the response will be returned to the parent function and the work will be continued till all parent functions finish?

Comment: Is the callback triggered more than once in any situation? If so you may encounter an issue with sending responses multiple times, which is a no go. Also you need to return some response in case of a falsey condition as well.

Comment: "I need to return a response to the user immediately without jumping up to the parent functions." — The call stack doesn't work like that.

Comment: "Is this behavior normal?" — What behaviour?

Comment: @Quentin does sending a final express response from a callback function as done in the example above aborts the work done after it from the parent functions(func2, and func1)? or the response will be returned to the parent function and the work will be continued till all parent functions finish?

Comment: Oh. That's what you mean. The function which makes Express send an HTTP response to the browser (which is distinct from what the word *return* usually means in programming) doesn't abort any other code. Why would it?